# Simulating mouse drag on cytoscape.js with cypress

Tags: cypress, cytoscape.js

I want to simulate a mouse drag programmatically with cypress.

In the below image, you can see that while I'm holding **Shift** button pressed I'm clicking to the cytoscape.js canvas with a mouse left-click and then not releasing it for a while.

[image: shift drag]

Here basically I'm pressing **Shift** and doing a mouse drag. I want to do this programmatically with cypress.

Below you can see what I tried so far.

```
// hold the shift key
cy.get('body').type('{shift}', { release: false });

cy.wait(1000);
// click to with mouse
cy.get('canvas').first().trigger('mousedown', 100, 100);
cy.wait(1000);
// click to with mouse
cy.get('canvas').first().trigger('mouseup', 400, 400);
```

`cy.get('canvas').first().click(100, 100);` simulates clicking successfully but I need more. Thank you.

Comment: You could record all the events that are fired when you create the rectangle in your app, (or look into the cytoscape code to see which ones are used) and then re-create them in Cypress. There are probably more events going on that just the ones you have.